# Sparklyr support for Spark 2.3.1

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I downloaded the spark version 2.3.1 and i get the following error :

```
Error in spark_version_from_home(spark_home, default = spark_version) : 
Failed to detect version from SPARK_HOME or SPARK_HOME_VERSION. Try passing the spark version explicitly.
```

On using spark_available_versions() the last result is 2.3.0.

Is 2.3.1 not supported with sparklyR yet? Is there any way I can bypass this or use any other explicit code to get over this?

Comment: search for how to set SPARK_HOME. sparklyr is not able to find your Spark instance path thats why likely this error is coming.

Comment: May be you can find the complete information here: https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/key/811TzxS93pjzZY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am working on windows 7, first verify that the environment variables are defined. *SPARK_HOME = c:\spark* and *Path = C:\spark\bin*. Then check the following commands.

```
Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME')
 "C:\\spark"
spark_version_from_home(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'))
 "2.3.1"
system('spark-submit --version')
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_151
Branch 
Compiled by user vanzin on 2018-06-01T20:37:04Z
Revision 
Url 
Type --help for more information.
```

Finally make the connection with spark.

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local") # work
```

Now as soon as your sparklyr question 0.8.4 supports spark 2.3.1, yes and no. Well in my case when using: **(throws an error)**

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3.1") #it does not work
Error in spark_install_find(version, hadoop_version, latest = FALSE, hint = TRUE) : 
  Spark version not installed. To install, use spark_install(version = "2.3.1")
```

If we verify the following dates, the last version of apache spark 2.3.1 was released (Jun 08 2018), while the latest update of sparklyr 0.8.4 was (May 25 2018) that is, it was launched a month earlier (spark 2.3.1 did not exist). Also when using the following commands:

```
spark_install(version = "2.3.1")
Error in spark_install_find(version, hadoop_version, installed_only = FALSE,:
spark_available_versions()
   spark
1  1.6.3
2  1.6.2
3  1.6.1
4  1.6.0
5  2.0.0
6  2.0.1
7  2.0.2
8  2.1.0
9  2.1.1
10 2.2.0
11 2.2.1
12 2.3.0
```

I think that the support solution to spark 2.3.1 completely (not partial as now) is to wait for the launch of [sparklyr 0.9.0](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/master/NEWS.md) or to communicate with maintenance manager package [Javier Luraschi](https://github.com/javierluraschi).

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I have had this issue for a long time.  You basically solved my problem with our great explanation and the history of package release.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I installed Spark from the package itself, and the error was fixed. It is important that the code sequence is as indicated.

```
library(sparklyr)

# Check the available version. I chose the most recent for personal reasons.
sparklyr::spark_available_versions() 

# Install SPARK and HADOOP (i kept the default)
sparklyr::spark_install(version = "3.3")

# connect spark
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "local")

# output console
> * Using Spark: 3.3.0
```

The main instructions found [on this page](https://therinspark.com/starting.html).

My system/pc/software

```
macOS Monterey 12.6
R version 4.1.3
IDE RStudio 2022.07.1+554 "Spotted Wakerobin"
```